# How is ADMM Separable?

Tags: optimization

I'm learning about ADMM by reading Boyd's paper [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf).

The paper says that ADMM is an improvement over the Method of Multipliers because the latter requires the minimization of the augmented Lagrangian:

$L_\rho(x,y) = f(x) + y^T (Ax − b)+(\rho/2)\lVert Ax − b\rVert^2_2$

which we cannot minimize in parallel because the added quadratic penalty term makes the function non-separable.

However, the paper says that ADMM requires minimization of the augmented Lagrangian functions:

$x^{k+1} = \underset{x}{\operatorname{argmin}} L_{\rho}(x,z^k,y^k)$

$z^{k+1} = \underset{z}{\operatorname{argmin}} L_{\rho}(x^{k+1},z^k,y^k)$

where the augmented Lagrangian is defined as

$L_{\rho}(x,z,y) = f(x) + g(z) + y^T(Ax + Bz − c)+(\rho/2)\lVert Ax + Bz − c\rVert^2_2$

The paper says that ADMM is an improvement because it has decomposability unlike the Method of Multipliers. However, shouldn't the augmented Lagrangian for ADMM also be non-separable because it also contains a quadratic penalty term $(\rho/2)\lVert Ax + Bz − c\rVert^2_2$ at the end? What allows it to be more decomposable?

Comment: By definition, ADMM solves for x and z one after another, not because that gives the same answer as optimizing for (x, z) jointly, but because convergence theory shows that it's good enough.